# Magento Error: Class_Magestore_Magenotification_Helper_Data not found

Tags: magento

Using Magento in admin, when I click the configuration tab, I get the following error:

```
"Fatal error: Class 'Magestore_Magenotification_Helper_Data' not found in."
```

Does anyone know why this would happen and how to fix it?

Comment: what files you have ? if you don't see xml file there.Put your extension directory structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this error occurs only if your Helper data is missing. Check your `Data.php` file at `your_code_pool/Magestore/Magenotification/Helper`. If that file does not exist, check your downloaded module or contact @Magestore if you install this module by Magento connect or create `Data.php` file with following code: (This may fix the above error only)

```
<?php
class Magestore_Magenotification_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the module. Go to `app/etc/modules` in your codebase and open file `Magestore_Magenotification.xml` and change the `<active>` node to `false`. Clear magento cache and reload the page.

Comment: in my magento folder ,in this path app\etc\modules, i dont have any name  file like that 'Magestore_Magenotifcation.xml'.

Comment: Elangovan, it was minor type mistake. I feel it is Magestore_Magenotification.xml . Check it one more time

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `config.xml` of the module and also verify the namespace of the module which must match with the module name space under `app/etc/modulename_namespace.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because I was on PHP 7.1 and not 5.6